# I cant use decimal conversion in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Next query is given me an error. I cant figure out. The error shows the next message: *fl.C AS Var **,** ((il.B:decimal -* **sintaxis error**....

```
BBB
AS (
    SELECT t.A  
        ,count(t.B) as B
    FROM AAA
    LEFT JOIN PUBLIC.BBB t ON (
            AAA.A= t.A
            )
    WHERE t.C= TIMESTAMP:from - INTERVAL '1 DAY'
    GROUP BY 1
    )
    ,

SELECT t.Id AS Id
    ,
    t.A AS A
    ,il.B AS B
    ,fl.C AS C
    ,il.B - fl.C AS Var
    ,
    ((il.B::decimal - fl.C::decimal) / fl.C::decimal) * 100::decimal AS D
    ,sum(t.G) AS G
    ,sum(t.H) AS H
FROM AAA t
LEFT JOIN BBB il ON (
        il.E = t.id     
        )
LEFT JOIN CCC fl ON (
        fl.F = t.id
        )
GROUP BY 1
    ,2
    ,3
    ,4
    ,5
    ,6
ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Its like I cant use ::decimal conversion at all. If I delete ::decimal conversion query will work but returning bad values for D (always 0).

All Columns types are Integer except **:from** and **:to** whose are DateTime.

They could contains nulls.

Comment: What error? What are the column types and why convert to decimal if the columns are already numeric? Are they integers? Contain nulls? Numbers stored as strings, which would be a design bug/ Grouping by column number is a very bad habit too

Comment: `100::decimal` isn't needed by the way, you could use `100.0`. But even that isn't needed. If you want to avoid integer division, the *only* conversion needed is for `fl.C`. Even that can be avoided if you change the order of the operands, eg `(il.B - fl.C)*100.0 / fl.C`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I think I posted the information you required. Hoping those could clarify the situation

Comment: `TIMESTAMP:from` is invalid as well. If `"from"` is a timestamp, then there is no need for any prefix. The only time the `timestamp` prefix is needed if you want to specify a typed _constant_

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I had to do it because I need it for substracting 1 to :from

Comment: If `:from` is a typed parameter with the type `timestamp` then all you need is `:from - interval '1 day'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It was my first approach but it doesnt work